# How to create a template string to output object contents ?

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects like this:

```
var students = [
  { 
    name : "Mike",
    track: "track-a",
    points : 40,
  },

  { 
    name : "james",
    track: "track-a",
    points : 61,
  },  
]

  students.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction (item, index) {

  for( var key in item ) {
    console.log(item[key])
  }
}
```

I want to output strings inside a div like this. 
If points > 50 I print pass otherwise I print failed then the name and track like this

```
Failed: Mike in track track-a
Passed: james in track track-1
```

How I can build a template string like this ?

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)!

```js
var students = [
  { 
    name : "Mike",
    track: "track-a",
    points : 40,
  },

  { 
    name : "james",
    track: "track-a",
    points : 61,
  },  
]

  students.forEach((student) => {
    console.log(`${student.points > 50 ? 'Passed' : 'Failed'}: ${student.name} in track ${student.track}`);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks alot I forgot about using template literals!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by mapping the array, you don't need an extra function, see below

```js
var students = [
  { 
    name : "Mike",
    track: "track-a",
    points : 40,
  },

  { 
    name : "james",
    track: "track-a",
    points : 61,
  },  
]

const myString = students.map(student => student.points > 50 ? `Passed: ${student.name} in track ${student.track}` : `Failed: ${student.name} in track ${student.track}`);

console.log(myString)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

```js
var a = "Hello";
var b = "World";
var template_string = `${a} ${b}!`; // Backticks here!

console.log( template_string )
```